# How to check who is spend 30 years in company

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How can I check how many employees are with the company for more than 30 years?

[image: pic of the question]

I don't need any other thing just anyone can tell me how can I check that

I am using Oracle SQL command line

Comment: Hi Akash. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please describe tables, which you need to use (please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us your SQL queries (they may not work, - it's fine, everyone will try to help you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be something like this:

```
select ename, sal, hiredate
from emp
where hiredate < add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12 * 30)
  and sal not between 1500 and 3000;
```

`HIREDATE` calculation is based on this:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select trunc(sysdate) today,
  2         add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12 * 30) thirty_years_ago
  3  from dual;

TODAY      THIRTY_YEA
---------- ----------
13.07.2020 13.07.1990

SQL>
```